# How do I insert from a table variable to a table with an identity column, while updating the the identity on the table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a SQL script to generate test data for our database. I'm generating the data in table variables (so I can track it later) and then inserting it into the real tables. The problem is, I need to track which rows I've added to the parent table, so that I can generate its child data later on in the script. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerId INT IDENTITY,
    Name       VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Order (
    OrderId    INT IDENTITY,
    CustomerId INT,
    Product    VARCHAR(50)
)
```

So, in my script, I create equivalent table variables:

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (
    CustomerId INT IDENTITY,
    Name       VARCHAR(50)
) -- populate customers

DECLARE @Order TABLE (
    OrderId    INT IDENTITY,
    CustomerId INT,
    Product    VARCHAR(50)
) -- populate orders
```

And I generate and insert sample data into each table variable.

Now, when I go to insert customers from my table variable into the real table, the `CustomerId` column in the table variable will become meaningless, as the real table has its own identity seed for its `CustomerId` column.

Is there a way I can track the new identity of each row inserted into the real table, in my table variable, so I can use a proper `CustomerId` for the order records? Or, is there a better way I should be going about this?

(Note: I originally started with an application to generate the test data, but it ran too slow during insert as > 1,000,000 records need to be generated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the data to the table with a cursor and use the built-in function `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last id which was inserted in the current scope (by your script).

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms190315.aspx) for more information on `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: Generating test data with a cursor is a terrible idea. And scope_identity() is fine but OUTPUT is better.

Comment: ouch, he wants to generate millions of rows. You're right, HLGEM! Didn't know `OUTPUT` yet.

Comment: This is as close to the solution I came up with as any of the answers. I generated the data in nested loops (leave me alone, it's just a one-time thing for now) and used `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to track which parent record I was on.

Answer (score 2):

WHy do you need identity values on the table variables? If you use just int, you can isnert the ids after the insert is done. Grab them using the output clause. YOu might need an input values and an output values table varaiable to get this just right like this:

```
DECLARE @CustomerInputs TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50) ) 
DECLARE @CustomerOutputs TABLE (CustomerId INT ,Name VARCHAR(50) ) 

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (name)
    OUTPUT inserted.Customerid, inserted.Name  INTO  @CustomerOutputs
SELECT Name FROM @CustomerInputs

SELECT * from @CustomerOutputs
```

Comment: How do you map the new id's in @CustomerOutputs to the old id's in @Order table when you move the orders to Order table? Using Name as a lookup is an option if Name is a candidate key in Customers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. If you can use it depends on your situation. You should not do it in production environment when users use your db.

```
-- Get the next identity values for Customer and Order
declare @NextCustomerID int
declare @NextOrderID int
set @NextCustomerID = IDENT_CURRENT('Customer')+1
set @NextOrderID = IDENT_CURRENT('Order')+1

-- Create tmp tables
create table #Customer (CustomerID int identity, Name varchar(50))
create table #Order (OrderID int identity, CustomerID int, Product varchar(50))

-- Reseed the identity columns in temp tables
dbcc checkident(#Customer, reseed, @NextCustomerID) 
dbcc checkident(#Order, reseed, @NextOrderID) 

-- Populate #Customer
-- Populate #Order

-- Allow insert to identity column on Customer
set identity_insert Customer on

-- Add rows to Customer
insert into Customer(CustomerId, Name)
select CustomerID, Name
from #Customer

-- Restore identity functionality on Customer
set identity_insert Customer off

-- Add rows to Order
set identity_insert [Order] on
insert into [Order](OrderID, CustomerID, Product)
select OrderID, CustomerID, Product
from #Order
set identity_insert [Order] off

-- Drop temp tables
drop table #Customer
drop table #Order

-- Check result
select * from [Order]
select * from Customer
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I'd do it its first obtain the `MAX(CustomerId)` from your Customer Table. Then I'd get rid of the `IDENTITY` column on your variable table and do my own CustomerId using `ROW_NUMBER()` and the MaxCustomerId. It should be something like this:

```
DECLARE @MaxCustomerId INT

SELECT @MaxCustomerId = ISNULL(MAX(CustomerId),0)
FROM Customer

DECLARE @Customer TABLE (
    CustomerId INT,
    Name       VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Customer(CustomerId, Name)
SELECT @MaxCustomerId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeColumn), Name
FROM YourDataTable
```

Or insert the values on a temp table, so you can use the same ids to fill your Order table.

Comment: I don't have control of the database schema; I won't be able to remove the identity specification.

Comment: @Adam Maras I meant to get rid of the `IDENTITY` column **only on your variable table**, that way, if you insert the values with a `ORDER BY CustomerId` clause on your Customer table, you should get the same Id that you already have on your variable table.